# I have an issue to display sprites in SDL

Tags: c, sdl

I am doing a platform game with SDL but I have a bug which I don't know how can I fix it.

I read a map that looks like this :

```
0=sprites/background.jpeg
1=sprites/dirt.jpeg

2
sprites/ww_left.png
sprites/ww_right.png

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I display 1 and 2 by simply blitting my picture and I display 0 by taking a pixels from my picture.

These are my displaying functions : 
https://github.com/vladydan/Darien_Reborn/blob/master/srcs/aff_map.c

And my problem is that the background overwrite my character sprites.
This is the display when I begin, it looks ok : 
[image]

And this is what happens when I move too much : 
[image]

If I continue to move to the right the display will be good again but there is always a moment where my sprite is overwritten.
I know where does it come from but I have no idea how to fix it, do you have an idea ?

Comment: Nice background, but crop the images a bit. Also, please put the *relevant* code in your post. Consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Emphasis on ***in your post***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 while (++i != 16)
    {
      pos.x = 0;
      j = -1;
      while (++j != 15)
    {
      if (game->map.map[i][j] == 1)
        SDL_BlitSurface(game->map.sprites[1], NULL, game->sdl.screen,
                &pos);
      else if ((game->map.map[i][j] == 0 || game->map.map[i][j] == 2))
        aff_background(game, pos);
      if (game->map.map[i][j] == 2)
        aff_sprite(game, pos);
      pos.x += 100;
    }
      pos.y += 52;
    }
  SDL_Flip(game->sdl.screen);
  return (0);
}
```

Seems like you're just arbitrarily rendering in some kind of logically-controlled order. I think the best thing to do is to render in descending order in the index that you've given us, rendering each layer one by one, with the first layer as the background.

You might also want to try and use `SDL_Texture` as well to use hardware acceleration, which might also fix your problems with the rendering. Perhaps it could be a rendering mode problem as well.

Comment: Nice idea I dont thought about it it should work. So I need to display all the background first, and then come back an other time in another loop to display dirt and sprite. Will do that, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Speculating: When you do direct pixel access, as in the function `aff_background`, you have to lock the surface, *especially* in hardware modes.

An easy way to check if this is your problem (not 100% conclusive), is to call `SDL_SetVideoMode` with the `SDL_SWSURFACE` flag instead. Even better check `SDL_MUSTLOCK`.

In general prefer blitting subimages to raw pixel writes. It's possible blits are queued or even done asynchronously, and the pixel writes interrupt the draw ordering.

Good luck.

**Edit:** After reading the other answer and going through your code a bit more, here's a hack that should give you the result you want,

```
while (++i != 16)
  {
    pos.x = 0;
    j = -1;
    while (++j != 15)
      {
        if (game->map.map[i][j] == 1)
          SDL_BlitSurface(game->map.sprites[1], NULL, game->sdl.screen,
                          &pos);
        else if ((game->map.map[i][j] == 0 || game->map.map[i][j] == 2))
          aff_background(game, pos);
        if (game->map.map[i][j] == 2)
          // record sprite starting position from map entry.
          sprite_start_pos = pos;
        pos.x += 100;
      }
    pos.y += 52;
  }
// write sprite image after everything else.
aff_sprite(game, sprite_start_pos);
SDL_Flip(game->sdl.screen);
```

Comment: No it's not my problem, the problem is that the half of the sprite of my character is overwritten by a square of background. For exemple I see a 2, I blit my character at position 200 and it ends at 300, then I see a 0 so I blit at posiiton 250 so the half of my sprit is gone. But I have no idea how can I fix it.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov You also might want to try and check the bounds on the rectangles for the maps and make sure the boundaries are not overlapping.

Comment: @VermillionAzure I think you were on the money with your answer. He's got the sprite (2) in the map, sprite render is occurring when that map entry is touched, but after movement the sprite is offset from that location, so the BG image is overwriting it.